# Resolving directory traversal

Tags: php

I keep seeing `/subsite/../global/css/file.css` when I look at my website's source code, and today I decided that I want to get rid of the unnecessary traversal in the path itself, so it becomes `/global/css/file.css`. I made myself a function which I now use for all paths. Here is the base of my function that accomplishes this:

```
function djpth($pth){
    // Split path at slashes (always receives path with forward slash)
    $pth = explode('/',$pth);
    // Iterate through the new array
    foreach ($pth as $i => $part)
        // If we find a traversal mark
        if ($part == '..')
            // We get rid of the folder name before the mark and the mark itself
            array_splice($pth,$i-1,2);
    // We join the array back together
    $pth = implode('/',$pth);
    // Then we return the resolved path
    return $pth;
}
```

I want to know if there's a better way to go about this, or if this is the best I can get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. ```
   djpth('/parent/subsite/../../global/css/file.css')
   ```

   returns

   ```
   /parent/../file.css
   ```

   I guess that is not what you want.
2. If the file exists I'd use the built-in [`realpath`](http://php.net/realpath) function. I guess it handles corner case like this and another ones better.

   (See also: *Effective Java, 2nd edition*, *Item 47: Know and use the libraries*)
3. `$pth` is used for multiple purposes. It would be easier to read a `$path` and a `$path_array`.
4. Abbreviations are hard to read, like `$pth`. Longer names would make the code more readable since readers don't have to decode the abbreviations every time and when they write/maintain the code don't have to guess which abbreviation the author uses.

   Furthermore, it's hard to pronounce (as well as `djpth`).

   > If you can’t pronounce it, you can’t discuss it without sounding like an idiot. “Well,
   >   over here on the bee cee arr three cee enn tee we have a pee ess zee kyew int, see?” This
   >   matters because programming is a social activity.

   Source: *Clean Code* by *Robert C. Martin*, *Use Pronounceable Names*, p21
5. Comments like this are just noise:

   > ```
   > // Iterate through the new array
   > ```

   It's obvious from the code itself. (*Clean Code* by *Robert C. Martin*: *Chapter 4: Comments, Noise Comments*)
6. > ```
   > $pth = implode('/',$pth);
   > // Then we return the resolved path
   > return $pth;
   > ```

   The comment above could be eliminated with a better variable name:

   ```
   $resolved_path = implode('/', $path_array);
   return $resolved_path;
   ```

Comment: I tested it and it seems to return `/global/css/file.css`. Thanks for the information, though.

Comment: @DJDavid98: Hm, I've also cheked it again. The result is the same as in the answer. PHP 5.3, if that's count.

Comment: You're right. This is just part of the function, so maybe I missed something that would fix this, but since then I modified it entirely. Here is the fixed up, current code: https://gist.github.com/DJDavid98/9427789